# Where to find postgresql.log on Manjaro

Tags: postgresql, manjaro

Using Manjaro, I freshly installed PostgreSQL with an user-defined data-directory. PostgreSQL is running fine, but I can't find the postgresql*.log(s), which I used to find in /var/log/postgresql on my former system. In ksystemlog I've seen an error, that I forced by

```
select * from non_exist_table;
```

but I'm wondering, if there is no longer the postgresql*.log.
Thank you!
[Here is my postgresql.conf](https://nowtransfer.de/postgresql.conf).

Comment: `select  pg_current_logfile()`

Comment: Look under data-directory/log

Comment: `select pg_current_logfile();` delivers: `NULL`

Comment: see my postgresql.conf first. Then 
`ls /mnt/Data/Tec/PostgreSQL/log not existing`

Answer (score 0):

With `logging_collector=off`, the logs will just spew to the stderr of the postmaster process.  That could have been redirected to a file, or just going to some tty someplace, or just be thrown away.  You would have to look at the code which launches the database server.